# A Kindle unlimited SF series--soldier in experiment that puts him in stasis, catastrophe strikes, he awakes and tries to rebuild civilization

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, artificial-intelligence

Having read many thousands of SF books over the years, I can't remember either the author or the title of this particular series.

Underground experimental stasis test facility partially collapsed, written off, and forgotten.  Soldier in stasis protected when world-wide catastrophe strikes.  He awakes, AI recognizes him as facility commander, and gets him to make critical AI repairs.

Well supplied with military equipment and food, soldier starts to rescue locals, and AI plots to have his genetic "Commander line" continue by getting him to rescue young women while putting down bandits. Soldier starts in local area and then works outward, bringing law and order, medicine, knowledge, technology, and trade to knit geographic areas together.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25520756-alice?

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [AL:ICE](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25520756-alice) by Charles W. Lamb?

> *Captain Jacob Thomas USMC is a divorced combat veteran just trying to
> get his life back on track. Returning to the Marine Corps after a
> failed attempt at reconciliation with his estranged wife, Jake
> volunteers for a DARPA experiment that catapults him into a future
> where humanity has been stripped of 200 years of technological
> advancements and more than half its population. With the help of a
> faceless benefactor named AL:ICE (Artificial Life: Intelligent
> Computing Environment), he escapes the confines of an abandoned lab
> facility and starts a journey to put earth back on a path to recovery.*

He wakes up and the AI gives him command of her facility.

> ‘And the second reason ‘ALICE continued ‘is I am bound by my core
> directive. I can only take direction from the facilities commander. I
> was never directed to expose myself to the outside world. In point of
> fact my primary instructions in that area are to keep this underground
> facility hidden and secret at all costs.’
>
> ‘Hell, since he died over 80 years ago, that’s going to be a problem’ Jake said.
>
> ‘That is not entirely correct’ ALICE responded ‘The person who was the facility commander died 81 years ago. With his
> passing the next surviving member in his chain of command assumed that
> responsibility.’
>
> ‘But you said everyone was killed?’ Jake queried.
>
> ‘Everyone from that command is dead but you. You are now the facilities commander’